# Manual Large Object Heap compaction (server GC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, garbage-collection, large-object-heap

A while ago we got blessed with the ability to manually compact the Large Object Heap (LOH). I'v read through the [GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx). What I cannot understand is if one should periodically set this property to [GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gclargeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx) or not in order to ensure the health of a long living IIS app pool i.e. manually request LOH compaction.

I do understand that this primarily is a matter of the particular design i.e. common request/response profile, WCF structure and so on. But are there general rules? Does one sound like "never do manual compaction before you are really sure you need that"?

Recently I had a round of refactoring on ASP.NET app I developed 7 years ago. When it was developed I would not give a dime for a thought it is ever going to handle requests 100k in length or it would have to prepare responses of that length. What a noob. It does every other second. Manual compaction helped for the period I was having it overhauled and inventing buffering and streaming where I could. Now I am thinking of leaving the manual compaction be just in case. Am I totally wrong?